# Apples and their volumes

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, volume

An apple has a peel that is 1cm thick and a total diameter of 12cm. What percentage of volume of the apple is the peel?

I tried 
$$\frac{\text{volume}(\text{radius of 6})-\text{volume}(\text{radius of 5})}{\text{volume}(\text{radius of 6})}$$
and got 42%. Is this correct?

Comment: That is one freakish apple...

Comment: I was just trying to make a sample question so I didn't actually give away the answer to my hw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{\frac{ 4\pi6^3}{3} - \frac{4\pi 5^3}{3}}{\frac{4\pi 6^3}{3}} = \frac{6^3 - 5^3}{6^3} = \frac{216-125}{216} = \frac{91}{216} \approx 0.42
$$
You are right.

Comment: Something to notice about this calculation is that the result has _little_ to do with the object being a sphere.  The exponent of "3" comes from the fact that this is a three-dimensional object; the "geometric factor" related to its shape cancels out.  You would have the same result for a _cube_ with sides of 6 cm. with a 1 cm. thick outer layer.  As long as the interior portion has the same "shape" (a "similar" figure), the ratio would have this value.

Comment: Nice remark..:)

Comment: Thank you.  I thought it was worth mentioning, as the concept has many applications and is connected to the _definition_ of "dimension" (even fractal ones!).